# Depth first search in java - cannot convert node to int

Tags: java, depth-first-search

I need to perform a depth-first search, but when I try to implement this code, I'm getting an error "cannot convert node to int." I understand that the types don't match, but I'm unsure how to correct it to get it to work. Below is my code for the method:

```
public void DFS(){
    int node = g.node;
    System.out.print("Depth First Traversal: ");
    boolean[] visited = new boolean[node];
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();

    for(int startIndex=0; startIndex<node; startIndex++){
        if(visited[startIndex]==false) {
            stack.push(startIndex);
            visited[startIndex] = true;
            while (stack.isEmpty() == false) {
                int nodeIndex = stack.pop();
                System.out.print(nodeIndex + " ");
                ArrayList<Node> nodeList = g.nodeList;
                for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.size(); i++) {
                    int dest = nodeList.get(i);
                    if (visited[dest] == false) {
                        stack.push(dest);
                        visited[dest] = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

And here is my graph class that im using.

```
public class Graph {

    ArrayList<Node> nodeList;
    ArrayList<Edge> edgeList;
    public boolean visited[];
    int node;

    public Graph() {
        nodeList = new ArrayList<Node>();
        edgeList = new ArrayList<Edge>();
    }

    public ArrayList<Node> getNodeList() {
        return nodeList;
    }

    public ArrayList<Edge> getEdgeList() {
        return edgeList;
    }

    public void addNode(Node n) {
        nodeList.add(n);
    }

    public void addEdge(Edge e) {
        edgeList.add(e);
    }
```

Here is my node class

```
public class Node {

    String name;
    String val; // The value of the Node
    String abbrev; // The abbreviation for the Node
    boolean visited;
    ArrayList<Edge> outgoingEdges;
    ArrayList<Edge> incomingEdges;//predecessor

    public Node(String theAbbrev) {
        setAbbrev(theAbbrev);
        val = null;
        name = null;
        outgoingEdges = new ArrayList<Edge>();
        incomingEdges = new ArrayList<Edge>();

    }

    public String getAbbrev() {
        return abbrev;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public ArrayList<Edge> getOutgoingEdges() {
        return outgoingEdges;
    }

    public ArrayList<Edge> getIncomingEdges() {
        return incomingEdges;
    }

    public void setAbbrev(String theAbbrev) {
        abbrev = theAbbrev;
    }

    public void setName(String theName) {
        name = theName;
    }

    public void setVal(String theVal) {
        val = theVal;
    }

    public void addOutgoingEdge(Edge e) {
        outgoingEdges.add(e);
    }

    public void addIncomingEdge(Edge e) {
        incomingEdges.add(e);
    }

    void visit() {
        visited = true;
    }

    void unvisit() {
        visited = false;
    }
}
```

And my edge Class

```
public class Edge {

    String label;
    Node tail;
    Node head;

    public Edge(Node tailNode, Node headNode, String theLabel) {
        setLabel(theLabel);
        setTail(tailNode);
        setHead(headNode);
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public Node getTail() {
        return tail;
    }

    public Node getHead() {
        return head;
    }

    public void setLabel(String s) {
        label = s;
    }

    public void setTail(Node n) {
        tail = n;
    }

    public void setHead(Node n) {
        head = n;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the definitions for `Node` and `Edge`

Comment: First of all, pls don't do that - it hurts me visited[dest] == false - you are comparing true/false to false to get true/false - does that make sense to you?

Answer (score 2):

You have there this

```
ArrayList<Node> nodeList = g.nodeList;
// ...
int dest = nodeList.get(i);
```

Obiously nodeList is list of `Nodes`, so you cannot save one of the `Node` it to `dest` which is number. If you want some number that is inside the `Node` you will have to write something like `int dest = nodeList.get(i).getIndex()` (just example, the name depends on what properites `Node` has)

Comment: They updated the question with the definition for `Node` if you want to amend your answer with the correct method.